# $I=\int_{-1}^2 \{|x-1| - \lfloor x \rfloor \}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$I=\int_{-1}^2  \{|x-1| - \lfloor x  \rfloor \}dx$$ I need to find value of $I$ . Here $\{\}$ represents fractional function that is $$\{x\}= x - [x]$$ so I broke the integral in integer limits $$I=\int_{-1}^0  \{-x+1 - 1\}dx + \int_{0}^1  \{-x+1 \}dx + \int_{1}^2  \{x-1 - 1\}dx$$
which comes $$1/2+1/2+1/2$$ but answer does not matches

Answer (score 1):

You did not get the right integrand. Let $ y = |x-1| - \lfloor x  \rfloor  $ then

> $$ \{y\} = y - \lfloor  y \rfloor \implies  \{|x-1| - \lfloor x  \rfloor \} = |x-1| - \lfloor x  \rfloor  - \lfloor  |x-1| - \lfloor x  \rfloor  \rfloor   $$